# invalid multibyte char (UTF-8) Error, Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to run an ruby script in rails with the command rails runner. The ruby file, looks something like this and should create new patients:

```
 Patient.create!({:vorname => 'Josepha', :nachnahme => 'Brecht', :geburtsdatum => '25.04.1963', :strasse => 'Umdorf', :ort => 'Wörthss', :plz => '93093'})
 Patient.create!({:vorname => 'Tumba', :nachnahme => 'Hoch', :geburtsdatum => '17.77.1956', :strasse => 'Hamaß 1', :ort => 'Brenn', :plz => '93189'})
```

But somehow my code has problems with the german language! Im programming beginner and do not know what i have to change! Thanks for help!

```
 C:\Sites\what>rails runner patienten.rb
 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
 ommands/runner.rb:51:in `eval': patienten.rb:2: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8) (
 SyntaxError)
 patienten.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
 ...> 'Schlossberg', :ort => 'Wörth', :plz => '93086'})
 ...                               ^
 patienten.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting $end
 ...:ort => 'Wörth', :plz => '93086'})
 ...                               ^
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
 3/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:51:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
 3/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
 3/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using Ruby 2.0? In 2.0, the problem disappears automatically.

Comment: You are missing code that reproduces the problem. Show us a stripped down example that only tries to load a small subset of your data. Also, what does `ruby -v` report?

Comment: @sawa can i simply update my ruby version with:  rvm install 2.0.0? or are other steps involved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What format is this file in? Are you sure it's UTF-8 and not [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) as is the default in Windows?

In Ruby 1.9, the header in your file needs to indicate the actual formatting used:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to experiment with others:

```
# encoding: Windows-1252
```

Another common format is [ISO Latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1):

```
# encoding: ISO-8859-1
```

Both 1252 and 8859-1 are single-byte character sets, each character is always one byte, where UTF-8 is variable length, each character is one *or more* bytes.

If you need to convert between formats, usually you can open in [an editor that's encoding aware](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and "Save As..." with the encoding you want. Otherwise you might try using [iconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) to convert it for you.

Comment: YOu are good!! I tried the whole day from 8 in the morning until now to run this programm! And now with # encoding: Windows-1252  it works! Thank you!! And have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

```rb
irb(main):088:0> "hi\x99!".encode("UTF-8", "Windows-1252")
=> "hi™!"
```

Justin Weiss has a great article about encoding in Ruby.
https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-steps-to-fix-encoding-problems-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
```

at the top of the file

Comment: `# encoding: utf-8` is sufficient. There's no need for decorations.

Answer (score 0):

put these two line at the top of the script.

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
```