# Calling a Commandline tool using Ruby

Tags: c, ruby, command-line, rubygems, extconf.rb

The commandline tool I trying to call basically converts a file to another format.

I'm following along using this [tutorial][1] but am running into trouble. I keep getting `invalid multibyte char (UTF-8) (SyntaxError)`

I'm just dumping my commandline tool (made using C) in the bin and am trying to get it to work. Could someone shed some light on how I can get this working?

Comment: Are you trying to create a gem? What version of ruby do you use? Can you give us a real example of how this tool work and why you would want to call through a ruby script?

Comment: Now I understand what you're doing but... That's kinda insecure. I don't think that people will use a pre-compiled 'C' binary on their systems.

Comment: do you have a source written in the ruby's c compatible?

Comment: @majioa Hi, this is my first time writing a gem using C so I'm not really sure. Please take a look at my edit. I have edited in my sources

Comment: can't access the repo

Comment: @atmosx Sorry, please try again. I read through one of the links majioa provided (below), and I'm guessing I should rewrite it, right? I have tomorrow free but would that really be necessary?

Comment: @atmosx I should also point out that I can give it a directory that doesn't exist and it'll still run without throwing any errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is related to UTF-8 encoding, which is the default encoding in ruby-2.x so I'm assuming you're using 1.8 or 1.9 and you should consider upgrading.

Try adding the following lines to the top of your script:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
```

Let us know if it works and have a look at [this thread for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859530/invalid-multibyte-char-utf-8-error-ruby).

EDIT: Now I understood what you want to do. Take a look [here](https://github.com/atmosx/f2bread/blob/master/bin/f2bread) for an example file which sits at the `bin/` directory. You can put your executable file to another directory like `data/` for example, and call through ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

prog = File.expand_path('../data/myprog', __FILE__)
ARGV.each do|a|
    system("#{prog} #{a}") # will return 'true' if run successfully
end
```

Okay try now. This should work with multiple files also, like

prog file1.doc file2.doc ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please see my edit. I tried adding the encoding but it's still not working

Comment: Thank you. You stated that it was kinda insecure -- why is that? How can I make it safer? (I have the original Makefile also)

Comment: Sure because it wouldn't accept arguments, I was only making a point. The above code should work fine now.

Comment: First, thank you for your patience.. It's still not working for me. Please see my edit in my question above -- I edited in more details as to what I'm trying to do. I must be doing something wrong

Comment: did you got it working? It is insecure because we don't know what is in the precompiled binary (the C program). So you have make the gem download and compile the gem in order for it to be used by others, otherwise you might be distributing a virus, a backdoor or any sort of malware as far as we know!

Comment: No, I never got it working but I could see how this would work in Ruby

Answer (score 1):

Please, read [the document](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2004/11/18/extending_ruby.htm), and [the document](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/ProgrammingRuby/book/ext_ruby.html) on how to make *C* soft compatible with *ruby*.

Some notes:

1. Place all files in proper folders for the gem;
2. Make the gem [*`extconf`*](http://search.apache.org/~rooneg/talks/ruby-extensions/ruby-extensions.html) compatible;
3. Don't put compiled binaries into *GitHub* source (in some restricted cases the precompiled binaries for *Windows OS* could be stored);
4. If you don't write an *OpenSource* project, don't publish it into *GitHub*, instead of it use *BitBucket*, and localhost (non *Rubygems.org*) to store the gem.

Comment: Thanks for the links & notes (pushed to git to only help explain what I was trying to do). For some reason I couldn't access the first link but I'll look through the second one