# Win7 Powershell echo > text file = Ruby2.2: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)?

Tags: ruby, powershell

Can I use echo from the powershell command line to create text files which Ruby can parse?

```
>>> echo "# foobar" > echo_test.rb
>>> ruby echo_test.rb
echo_test.rb:1: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
```

Notepad++ reports the encoding as UCS-2 Little Endian. I also tried echo'ing with the the header options mentioned in this thread:
[invalid multibyte char (UTF-8) Error, Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859530/invalid-multibyte-char-utf-8-error-ruby)

e.g.

```
>>> echo "# encoding: utf-8" > echo_test.rb
```

and got the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the encoding if you pipe it into `Out-File`

Example:

```
'# foobar' | Out-File -FilePath echo_test.rb -Encoding ascii
ruby echo_test.rb
```

Comment: That works nicely! I'll admit total ignorance regarding text encoding. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've only played with Ruby a little, so I can't speak much to the best practices for that unfortunately.