# Get list of subfolders from a given folder in JRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I use `JRuby` in `SikuliX IDE` to get list of folders and its subfolders recursively and store its absolute paths(which may contains also dotted characters) in an array. I tried to use following code:

```
records = Dir.glob 'C:/_private/Files/**/*/'
```

I got error message:

> [error] SyntaxError ( invalid multibyte char (UTF-8) )

Expected output:

```
C:/_private/Files/dir1
C:/_private/Files/dir1/subdir1
C:/_private/Files/dir1/subdir2
C:/_private/Files/dir2
C:/_private/Files/dir2/subdir1
C:/_private/Files/dir2/subdir2
```

Comment: Look this url may its helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859530/invalid-multibyte-char-utf-8-error-ruby . Also let me

Comment: @Kandy : Problem is in absolute path, but not sure, how should I escape it.

Comment: on which operating system you are working

Comment: @Kandy : I use it on Windows.

Comment: can you provide your more code so I look what actually happening. I have installed ruby in my system

Comment: @Kandy : I just use it in a loop: `records.each do |item|`

Comment: Can you please include in your question example directory names that you expect to be returned? This will allow your example and your error to be recreated by anyone answering this question.

Comment: @anothermh : I added expected output.

Comment: I think you are looking for folders only so I posted answer below check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check new stuff it producing expected result -

```
 records = Dir.glob('/E:/ISSUE_Folder/**/*.*')

 records.each do |item|
   puts File.dirname(item)
 end
```

[image]

As you see its going to every folder and sub folder

Comment: It isn't working, if there are dotted characters in path and first of all I need only full path to subdirectories.

Comment: dotted means can you send your path

Comment: I am not able to get you.Just edit some more code in your question so that i can reproduce your error at my side.

Comment: I edited question. Problem with your output is, that just subfolders are needed, files are not, but it should work recursively to get all the subfolders.

Comment: @plaidshirt I have edited my answer and hope it matches your requirement.

Comment: I added sample expected output to question. I need name of subfolders, not filenames.

Answer (score 1):

My rails app have `config` folder & it have number of files & subfolders, so getting only folders in `config`,

I used `ap` below provided by [awesome_print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print) gem

```
> ap Dir.glob "#{Rails.root}/config/**/"
[
    [0] "/home/ray/projects/example_app/config/",
    [1] "/home/ray/projects/example_app/config/initializers/",
    [2] "/home/ray/projects/example_app/config/locales/",
    [3] "/home/ray/projects/example_app/config/environments/"
]
```

I have `test` folder inside `config/locales/`, It is also got by following query.

```
> ap Dir.glob "#{Rails.root}/config/**/**/"
[
    [0] "/home/ray/projects/example_app/config/",
    [1] "/home/ray/projects/example_app/config/initializers/",
    [2] "/home/ray/projects/example_app/config/locales/",
    [3] "/home/ray/projects/example_app/config/locales/test/",
    [4] "/home/ray/projects/example_app/config/environments/"
]
```

For further search for sub-folders on third level hierarchy, I will use `"#{Rails.root}/config/**/**/**/"`

**Update:**

You can try with following for **windows**,

```
irb(main):022:0> Dir.glob("D:/sd/*/")  # first hierarchy 
=> ["D:/sd/df/", "D:/sd/dff/"]   

irb(main):023:0> Dir.glob("D:/sd/*")
=> ["D:/sd/351px-Nvidia_logo.png", "D:/sd/df", "D:/sd/dff"]

irb(main):024:0> Dir.glob("D:/sd/*/*/") # second hierarchy
=> ["D:/sd/dff/ty/"]

irb(main):025:0> Dir.glob("D:/sd/*/*")
=> ["D:/sd/df/351px-Nvidia_logo2.png", "D:/sd/dff/ty"]
```

You can further get result by adding first and second hierarchy (commented in above) subfolders

Comment: Thanks, but how could I use absolute path in Windows? C:/ notation seems invalid.

Comment: @plaidshirt I checked in windows, check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your JRuby be using less than or equal to ruby 1.9

In Ruby 1.9, the header in your file needs to indicate encoding format.

Add this line at top

`# encoding: UTF-8`